# Twig equivalent of lcfirst

Tags: twig

I'm not able to find a equivalent of lcfirst php function in Twig, my need is to lower only the first letter of a word ?
If such function doesn't exist, what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in [this issue on Github](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1652), you could use:

```
{{ foo[:1]|lower ~ foo[1:] }}
```

See [this working example](https://twigfiddle.com/aik5sj).

Comment: Same that capitalize function, result is "Hello world" in your fiddle.
My need is : input = "HELLO", ouput = "hELLO"

Comment: Oh sorry, I've updated with `lower` instead of `upper`. Also the fiddle is updated

Answer (score 2):

Just add the function into `twig` by chaining it with a filter, e.g.

```php
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('lcfirst', 'lcfirst'));
```

Then use it inside any twig template like

```html
{{ string | lcfirst }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capitalize filter:

```
{{ 'my first car'|capitalize }}


{# outputs 'My first car' #}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/capitalize.html